# Multiplying both sides of an equation in proofs

Tags: group-theory, axioms

I'm learning the basics of group theory, and must justify every step of a proof by referring to the basic axioms/theorems. Which axioms/theorems justify multiplying or adding an element of a group to both sides of an equation?

[image]

Comment: It depends on how deep you want to go. It's not a group theory axiom, it's a "mathematics axiom", (in $\sf ZFC$ it would boil down to the [Axiom of Extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality)). Morally, if you have "two" equal objects, whatever you do to them results in yet two equal objects.

Comment: By the way, the identities $aa^{-1}=e$ and $a^{-1}a=e$ tell us that $a$ satisfies the required properties for being the inverse of $a^{-1}$, so it *is* the inverse of $a^{-1}$. No manipulation is necessary. As to your question, have you got doubts when passing from $2x=4$ to $x=2$ in elementary algebra? I guess not. Well, it's the same, because you multiply both sides by $1/2$.

Comment: If $a = b$ then $a$ and $b$ are the same element (call it "fred").  A group has a binary operation and doing the operation on two elements will constantly yield the same result.  So fred$\times c$ will be an elment (call it "sally") and fred$\times c$ will always be sally.  So if $a = b$ and $a\times c = b\times c$ because $a$ and $b$ diferent ways of saying  fred, and $a\times c$ will be fred$\times c$ and $b\times c$ is just fred$\times c$.

Comment: "As to your question, have you got doubts when passing from 2x=4 to x=2 in elementary algebra? "  I imagine the OP doesn't but that the OP doesn't know how one can justify that by group axioms.  In a way it's not really fair the we say "you must justify everything" and then when comes to justifying things actually exists we say "of things are what they are! We don't have to justify *that*, duh".  And as Git Gud points out we *do* have existence axioms for that.  But usually "equality" is considered "is the same specific thing" and whatever you do to the thing, is done to the thing is assumed.

Comment: Anyway, it's a *good* question.  I'm sorry that my way of dealing with it isn't a good answer.

Comment: See [Axioms for group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Definition): a *group* is a set $G$ with an operation (call it: *multiplication*) such that: (i) $G$ is closed under the operation, (ii) ...

Comment: Thus, we have $a \in G$ and its *inverse* $a^{-1}$. The last one is in $G$ by axiom 4 and in turn has an inverse : $(a^{-1})^{-1}$. Their product is the *identity element* $e$ (by ax.3 and 4). Thus we have the equation: $a^{-1}(a^{-1})^{-1}=e$. By axioms for equality, the product of the LHS by $a$ is equal to the product of the RHS by $a$.

Comment: Thus, we need also the [theory of equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms) that, being ubiquitous in mathematics, it is considered usually part of the "underlying logic".

Comment: You can find a formal treatment of group theory in the context of first order logic with eqaulity into D.Goldrei, [Propositional and Predicate Calculus: A Model of Argument](https://books.google.it/books?id=B7UGnBbb2JoC&pg=PA198).

Answer (score 0):

Group operation is first and foremost a *map*, say $\star\colon G\times G\to G$. Therefore, if $a,b\in G$ are such that $a=b$, then $(a,g)=(b,g)$ for every $g\in G$, and hence $\star(a,g)=\star(b,g)$, or (in infix notation) $a\star g=b\star g$. So, in groups, $a=b\Longrightarrow ag=bg$ for every $g$.