# Question about properties of "equality"

Tags: definition, axioms

There is one thing that is used in a lot proofs but I have never heard of it as an axiom or a theorem. I'm talking about the fact that if $x$ and $y$ are numbers such that $$x=y$$ then $$f(x)=f(y).$$ And it seems true but I have never heard of it as an axiom (or theorem but I don't think that it can be a theorem). The only way (which I see) to prove it, is to somehow use the Peano axioms and one of ways to construct natural numbers but I don't imagine it in practice. So is there such an axiom or theorem?

Comment: that's part of the definition of a function. Specifically from a set theoretic standpoint, a function $f:A \rightarrow B$ is a subset $f \subset A \times B$ such that $\forall a \in A, \exists$ unique $ b \in B$ such that $(a,b) \in f$. We abbreviate $(a,b) \in f$ to $f(a) = b$. Hence by the uniqueness, if $x = y$ in $A$, we know that $(x, f(x))$ and $(y,f(y))$ must be the same ordered pair. Ergo, $f(x) = f(y)$ as members of $B$

Comment: @Joe What definition you're talking about ? The one that uses tuples and sets or other ?

Comment: @ЮрійЯрош That is the definition of a function from the point of view of set theory...

Comment: Related: [Multiplying both sides of an equation in proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2696628/multiplying-both-sides-of-an-equation-in-proofs).

Comment: @XanderHenderson I know. But it's, maybe, the most rigorous one.

Comment: @GitGud Thanks.

Comment: $x=y \implies f(x)=f(y)$ is trivially true by definition of function, if the function is defined for x=y, the reverse implication $ f(x)=f(y) \implies x=y$ is more interesting

Comment: @ЮрійЯрош What do you mean by "the most rigorous one?"  It is the *definition*, from the point of view of set theory.  How can it not be rigorous?

Comment: @XanderHenderson I meant that definitions like "it is a rule that assigns some input to some output" is not rigouros.

Comment: Well, the logic I study has that as a logical axiom. So you can use it in any deduction and from soundness theorem it is valid as well.

Comment: More formally $(x_1=y_1) \land (x_2=y_2)... \implies f(x_1.x_2...)=f(y_1,y_2...)$

Comment: @Sorfosh Thanks, actually, it was what I was interested in. Because I was thinking that something is left undefined.

Comment: @ЮрійЯрош The definition you give is not nonrigorous; it is simply a bad definition.  It can be made better by further defining what is meant by a "rule", an "input", and an "output," but those terms are left undefined in most texts that use such a definition.  In the definition that Joe gives, all of the objects and terms used to define a function are also perfectly well-defined.

Comment: See [First-order logic: equality axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms).

Comment: @XanderHenderson Yes. It seems to be rigorous but the only thing I'm not sure in the proof is words "the same ordered pair".

Comment: @ЮрійЯрош From a set-theoretic standpoint, if you define the ordered pair $(x,y)$ to be the set $\{x, \{y \} \}$, being "the same ordered pair" follows easily as standard set equality.

Comment: @Joe Then it is clear for me, Thanks.

Comment: @Joe Sorry, I have one more question. You said that "x=y in A so (x,f(x)) and (y,f(y)) are the same ordered pair". Do you use the fact that " x" and "y" are the same things there ? Or am I wrong ?

Comment: @ЮрійЯрош Yes. Since $x$ and $y$ are sets, we have that $\{x, \{f(x)\}\} \in f$ and $\{y, \{f(y)\}\} \in f$. Using the fact that $x=y$ as sets, we have:$\{x, \{f(x)\}\} \in f$ and $\{x, \{f(y)\}\} \in f$. But these must be the same set (uniqueness property), so $\{f(x)\} = \{f(y)\}$. Both of these sets have one element, so they must be the same element. Ergo, $f(x) = f(y)$ as sets.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your question lies in the meaning of "equality". The statement
$$
x = y
$$
says (in everyday mathematics) that "$x$" and "$y$" are different names for the same object. So of course it follows that
$$
f(x) = f(y) \ .
$$

This doesn't depend on $x$ and $y$ being numbers, or even on $f$ being a function. It can be any expression in $x$ and $y$.

I say "in everyday mathematics" because if you're studying foundations you need to be much more careful about things and the names of things.

For an extended discussion, see this nice essay by Barry Mazur:
http://www.math.harvard.edu/~mazur/preprints/when_is_one.pdf

Comment: "In everyday math" I agree with you. But I thought that there is something about it from the point of view of foundations.

Comment: @ЮрійЯрош Perhaps. To find out here you'd have to make it explicitly a question   about foundations - even more basic than Peano postulates. Ask it as a separate question rather than editing this one. You might enjoy the article I link to in my answer.

Comment: OK, thanks for the article, I will read it.