# Why can I replace equal expressions in mathematical statements?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, axioms

Why can I replace equal expressions in any mathematical statement? Is there a proof for that? Who "says" that replacing the statements is valid?

Example:

If:
$$
A=B \qquad
C+A^2 = D
$$

Then:
$$
C+B^2=D
$$

Note: that $A,B,C,D$ are mathematical expressions (This is just one example, I ask why it works for **every** mathematical statement, not just in equations.)

Comment: What definition of equality are you using? In some formal systems, being able to substitute is exactly the definition of equality, so you get this ability tautologically.

Comment: [Substitution for equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms): "if $A=B$, then $(\varphi(A) \to \varphi(B))$ where $\varphi$ is a formula (a mathematical statement).

Comment: [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1100564/is-there-a-law-that-you-can-add-or-multiply-to-both-sides-of-an-equation) is relevant

Comment: This is a great question, but it is a duplicate. Note that the duplicate I've linked to mentions fields specifically in the question, but the **answer** is really at this level of generality.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking, when you know that two mathematical expressions are equal you know that they are different names for the same object. Then substituting one for the other is clearly OK.

See [Question about properties of "equality"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2698888/question-about-properties-of-equality/2698921#2698921) (which I would post as a duplicate if that question had an accepted answer).